# How do I convert an array of pixels back to an image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a .txt file which has a list of total m*n : (r,g,b) values in it. What I need to do is , I have to read these values and reconstruct the m wide and h tall image from them and save the image.
Please guide in both these tasks?

Comment: You should have shown some lines of that file.

Comment: Please give us some more detail about the format of the input file, and also whether the size of the image is known beforehand. Once these details are known, it is easy to load the data into a numpy array that can be shown into an image using opencv.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pylab to draw a image from a array

```
import pylab 
pylab.imshow(imarray)
```

if you are not familar with  python about computer version
you can read  the book Programming Computer Vision with Python writen by Jan Erik Solem  http://programmingcomputervision.com